# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to get the result `array(['0th', '1th', '2th', '3th', '4th'])` by operating on the whole array given by `np.array(range(5)).astype(str)`. I tried this:

```
>>> np.array(range(5))
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> np.array(range(5))*2
array([0, 2, 4, 6, 8])
>>> np.array(range(5)).astype(str)
array(['0', '1', '2', '3', '4'],
  dtype='<U24')
>>> np.array(range(5)).astype(str)+"th"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'
```

I know I can do this using a list comprehension:

```
[ x+"th" for x in np.array(range(5)).astype(str) ]  # can get the result,
```

but I would prefer a vectorized way to do the same thing, such as:

```
pandas.date_range("20150105",periods=16*7,freq="D").format(formatter=lambda x:x.strftime("%Y%m%d"))
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Why don't you like the list comprehension?  In my tests it is faster.  Your `pandas` expression returns a list.

Comment: A faster list operation, `map('{}th'.format, range(N))`, modeled on the Pandas `format`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
>>> np.core.defchararray.add(np.arange(5).astype(str), 'th')
array(['0th', '1th', '2th', '3th', '4th'], 
      dtype='|S26')
```

Comment: or just `np.char.add(np.arange(5).astype(str).astype(str), 'th')`

Comment: it is `np.char.add(np.arange(5).astype(str), 'th')` better than `np.char.add(np.arange(5).astype(str).astype(str), 'th')`,one astype(str) is ok.

Comment: @it_is_a_literature Oops, the second `.astype(str)` was just a typo (it shouldn't make any difference)

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

```
>>> np.array([str(a) + 'th' for a in range(5)])
array(['0th', '1th', '2th', '3th', '4th'], 
      dtype='|S3')
```

Answer (score 0):

I currently don't have the Numpy package in my computer, so I can't really test but here is my first thought.

`np.array(range(5)).astype(str)` seems to return a `ndarray` element of the form `ndarray(list, str)`

Does this works?:
`print [ x+"th" for x in np.array(range(5)).astype(str)[0] ]`